# How to set two tooltips in ChartJs line chart to be visible at the same time, one which was clicked, and other which was hovered?

Tags: onclick, chart.js, tooltip, linechart

Is it possible for tooltip in ChartJs Line chart remain on screen after clicking on it, but also to be able to hover on other data points and be able to see 2 tooltips at the same time, one which was clicked and other tooltip which was hovered? I am using ChartJs 3.9.1

I tried to put events: ['clicked', ...and other things], but this is not working for me, because I am losing hover effect, or if I add moseleave in array, then it overide clicked tooltip.

Also tried onClick method to implement in options, but I couldn't figure it out how to manipulate correctly with tooltip.

And I was learning about custom tooltips, but didn't try to implement it, to many things to learn, and I don't have so much time to spend to learn how to make custom tooltip.